# Problems to install php intl with Xampp (MacOs)

Tags: php, macos, xampp, php-7, intl

I´m installed Xampp in my Mac, the last version with Php7, all works fine, but in my Php proyect I´m using this function:

```
numfmt_format_currency()
```

I need install the intl, and edit the php.ini with this line:

```
extension="intl.so”
```

The problem is, I can´t install the intl, I use this command:

```
sudo pecl install intl
```

But returns me this console error:

```
/private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/intl_error.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ext/standard/php_smart_str.h' file not found
#include <ext/standard/php_smart_str.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

After, I try download the ntl-3.0.0.tgz from [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/intl), and Install whith this command:

```
sudo pear install intl-3.0.0.tgz
```

But return me this:

```
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/intl" - package pecl/intl can be installed with "pecl install intl"
install failed
```

I'm desperate, how can I install intl?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: nope man.......

Comment: What about now?

Comment: could you find a solution to this?

Comment: Not solution :(

Comment: have you tried using brew instead to manage php and install this extension?

Comment: Any one found the solutions ?????

Comment: Have you given my answer a try? I am no longer using a Mac, but it did work when I worked on one. A feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PHP package from https://php-osx.liip.ch/. It already includes the intl extension.

> This package installs the (usually) latest PHP 7.2/7.1/7.0/5.6/5.5/5.4/5.3 on OS X 10.6 (aka Snow Leopard), OS X 10.7 (aka Lion) and OS X 10.8 (aka Mountain Lion) and OS X 10.9 (aka Mavericks) and OS X 10.10 (aka Yosemite) and OS X 10.11 (aka El Capitan) and macOS 10.12 (aka Sierra) and macOS 10.13 (aka High Sierra) in /usr/local/php5. It installs many useful extensions (see below) and ini-settings and is what we at Liip use for our development. It's especially suited for Symfony 2 development. It also provides a decent php.ini with all settings configured according to "Best Practices".

Installation of PHP 7.2 is done via `curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.2`.

For more information have a look at the site and FAQ section.